# Flutter Application publish Version code 1 has already been used. Try another version code

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I wont to upload my update number 12 code version to correct some bugs and I test many Solutions but always When I upload my appbundels  Google play console return this messages "Version code 1 has already been used. Try another version code."

Last App bundle uploaded
11 (1.0.0)

pubspec.yaml
version: 1.0.2+2

### android/app/build.gradle

```
`def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '2'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0.2'
}`
```

### android/local.proprieety

flutter.versionCode=2
flutter.versionName=1.0.2

- I change many time my version code to 1.0.0+13
- I run pub get
- I restar my computer and my IDE
- I run App before build bundels

Comment: I test flutter Clean and flutter pub get nothing

Comment: in my app-realise.aab I have Version name 2.0.0 and  version code 2 but not accepted by google play

Answer (score 0):

Update version:1.0.2+3 in pubspec.yaml.
and save it
and run these commands :

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
3. flutter build appbundle

Answer (score 0):

With my experience for Android release.

In pubspec.yaml you have to declare 'version:N.N.N+C'

When you compile the application, the *local.properties* is re-generated splitting this version value on '+' character in two variables:
flutter.versionName=N.N.N
flutter.versionCode=C

Google Console requires that versionCode is unique, usually incrementing by 1 at each release.